# Does "sprintf" usage in code need to free the memory?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am developing a code in Arduino, in which I have used "sprintf", need to know whether I should use "free" after that to de-allocate memory or it is not required?

As when I am using "free" it is disabling serial communication, if it is not necessary I could bypass it & code is working fine with it.

I have attached code snippet

Please suggest

Thank you

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
}

int toString(char a[]) {
  int i, j ;
  int dec = 0;
  for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    dec = dec * 10 + ( a[i] - '0' );
  }
  return dec;
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int val1 = 2;
  int val2 = 1;
  int val3 = 1;
  int val4 = 8;
  char valread[10];
  sprintf(valread, "%c%c%c%c", val1,val2,val3,val4);
  int VerifyMainpower = toString(valread);      
  free(valread);
  delay(5);
  if(VerifyMainpower < 2100 || VerifyMainpower > 2300){
    Serial.print("Error003_02");
    }  
  }
```

Comment: Whether you should explicitly free some block of memory depends on how you allocate it and has nothing to do with how you use that block of memory.

Comment: `char valread[10];` is a static array allocated on the stack. Never try to free something allocated on the stack. And please don't use sprintf but snprintf

Comment: `free` what you `malloc`. `delete` what you `new`. Ape shall not kill Ape. That is the law.

Answer (score 4):

`sprintf()` simply writes into the buffer space you provide for it; it neither knows nor cares how the buffer was allocated; that's up to your code to deal with.

In the code shown, you should not be calling `free(valread)` because you didn't allocate it with `malloc()` (or `calloc()`).  You should only `free()` memory that you previously allocated from the heap.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library won't do any dynamic memory operations (except functions like `malloc` which are designed to do the work).

So, if the parameter is a local variable, you shouldn't free the memory. If the parameter is a pointer that created from `malloc`, you should finally free it.